# NextJS API error : "TypeError: res.status is not a function"

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror

## Context

I'm using `NextJS v11.1.1-canary.11`, `React v17.0.2` and `Typescript v4.3.5`.

I wanted to create a simple API endpoint, based on [NextJS Typescript documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#api-routes), so I've created a file in `pages/proxy` folder named `login.tsx` that is containing very simple API code:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default function Login(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

## My problem

When I try to call that API endpoint, an error occurs :

```
TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at Login (C:\wamp64\www\project-front\.next\server\pages\proxy\login.js:19:7)
```

Full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/5NSLYyqp)

I've done researches and I can't find any case like me on Google or Stackoverflow, I'm new in NextJS so I'm probably misunderstanding something. Does someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your example works fine.

You can solve this issue by placing your `login.ts` file at `pages/api/{whatever_you_want}`

Next docs:

> Any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page. They are server-side only bundles and won't increase your client-side bundle size.

Comment: where is the pages directory? Did you place it in your root directory where also the package.json is or did you place it in the app directory?
It did not work for me if I place it in the root directory.
I have the following directory structure: pages -> api -> hello -> routes.ts
Inside routes.ts is `export async function handler(request: Request) {
  return new Response("Hello, Next.js!");
}`
I can not reach the endpoint via localhost:3000/api/hello 
OR localhost:3000/pages/api/hello

Comment: There are now 2 routing methods in Next.js: the App Router (new since Next 13) and the Page Router (the router that was there in previous versions)

For more information, I recommend you look at [the documentation for migrating from the Pages router to App](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app), as well as [this topic on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570208/what-different-between-app-router-and-pages-router-in-next-js)

It seems like you're using the App router, let me know if you need help

Comment: Here's also [a section of the Next documentation explaining where to put your files for the API](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#api-routes). Also have a look at [the Route Handlers documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes), it might help.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, in my case it was because i configured the runtime to use **"experimental-edge"**.

If you comment it, it will work, it might be a bug on the canary version

```
// in next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    transpilePackages: ["ui"],
    // runtime: "experimental-edge",
  },
};
```

Comment: I had configured it to use edge in the file itself: `export const config = {  runtime: 'edge', };`

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the order of your input params is `(req, res)`:

```
// Wrong ❌
// Will throw `TypeError: res.status is not a function`
export default function Login(res, req) {
   ...
   res.status(200).json({ success: "ok" })
}

// Right ✅
export default function Login(req, res) {
   ...
   res.status(200).json({ success: "ok" })
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the code I shared, it's not related to that, I just needed to put my `login.ts` at `pages/api/{whatever_you_want}`, as @ismail-el-moudni said.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice was helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the App Router, the response shoud be returned:

```
"use server";

import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

async function GET(req: NextRequest) {

    return new Response("Hello", {
        status: 200
    })
}

export { GET }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are using App Router and want to return JSON, here is Matei's modified code:

```js
"use server";

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.json(
    { key: "value" },
    {
      status: 200,
    }
  );
}

export { GET };
```