# NextJS API route error "TypeError: res.status is not a function"

Tags: api, next.js, typeerror

I created a simple api endpoint named getFeed which is supposed to get feed content from Sanity CMS. But unexpectedly the endpoint is throwing an error "res.status is not a function". I know there is a [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564777/nextjs-api-error-typeerror-res-status-is-not-a-function) , but in my case the api endpoint file is stored in the supposed pages/api directory. Here is the code snippet below.

```
import { NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { client } from '../../lib/sanity/sanity'

export default async function getFeed(res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const feeds = await client.fetch(
      `*[_type == "post"]
      {
        _createdAt,
        title,
        description,
        picture,
        postDocId,
        postedByUserId,
        postedByUserName,
        postedByUserImage
      }`
    )
    return res.status(200).json({ feeds })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Couldn't get post feed:\n", error })
  }
}
```

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZqu.png)

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) handlers receive two arguments, a request in the first one and a response as the second one. You're accessing the `req` object in your code, which doesn't have that method. Your function signature should be `export default async function getFeed(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify also the `req` parameter and add a type to the response:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

interface Data {
    message?: string;
    feeds?: <type-of-feeds>[];
}

export default async function getFeed(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) { ... }
```