# What is different between App Router and Pages Router in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I have started learning next.js in Next.js official documentation:

[next.js official document](https://nextjs.org/docs)

The document mentions two router features; App Router and Pages Router.

What's the difference between them, and in what scenarios is one more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Some info here [Next.js’s New App Vs. Pages Router: A Detailed Comparison](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/next-jss-new-app-vs-pages-router-a-detailed-comparison-46f846963af5)

Comment: @kiranvj If only the complete article was available for non-medium members as well.

Comment: @0_0perplexed Try Incognito mode.

Comment: @kiranvj Still can't access the complete article.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Well to easily understand it, I have created the below table of difference, based on your requirement you can use desired router however `app router` is prefered in the official docs.

| Feature | App Router | Pages Router |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Routing type | Server-centric | Client-side |
| Support for Server Components | Yes | No |
| Complexity | More complex | Simpler |
| Performance | Better | Worse |
| Flexibility | More flexible | Less flexible |

---

*Also refer latest Nextjs code templates*
[**Next.js 13/14+ Power Snippets | TypeScript/Javascript**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krishnaacharyaa.nextjs-13-power-snippets)

*It includes wide range of code snippets for both `ts` and `js`. Find all snippets* [**here**](https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/nextjs-13-power-snippets/blob/HEAD/documentation/snippets.md)

Comment: Any link to the source ?

Comment: It is actually my inference from the documentation @PatrissolKenfack

Comment: I would say, in regards to static site generation, pages router is more flexible

Comment: If you have inferred from the documentation, please link the inference. It feels like an answer to advertise something you made yourself.

Comment: After completed some projects, page route seems more flexible and better performance.

Comment: This answer seems inaccurate and potentially biased, it has been shown that in fact Pages has greater performance - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q2q2gs0nAI

Comment: I'm now learning app router but I'm very comfortable with page router. Could app router support custom node servers as seamlessly as page router?

Answer (score 19):

Key Differences:

| Feature | App Router | Page Router |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File-based routing | Uses nested folders to define routes | Files directly represent routes |
| Components | Server Components by default | Client Components by default |
| Data fetching | fetch function for data fetching | getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, getInitialProps |
| Layouts | Layouts can be nested and dynamic | Layouts are static |
| Dynamic routes | Supported, but syntax differs | Supported |
| Client-side navigation | Supported with router.push | Supported with Link component |
| Priority | Takes precedence over Page Router | Fallback if no matching route in App Router |

Additional Considerations:

- SEO: Pages in the app directory are server-rendered by default, potentially better for SEO.
- Performance: Server Components in the app directory can offer performance benefits.
- Flexibility: App Router provides more flexibility for nested layouts and data fetching.
- Migration: Migrating existing projects to App Router might require some effort.

Recommendations:

- New Projects: Start with App Router for its modern features and flexibility.
- Existing Projects: Evaluate potential benefits before migrating to App Router.
- Simple Routing: Page Router might suffice for smaller projects with straightforward routing needs.
- Complex Routing and Data Requirements: App Router is likely a better choice.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to getStaticProps with app router as with page router? I.e. fetch a pre generated page on-the-fly without server creating it?

Answer (score 2):

The app router might be the better option for single page applications.
The pages variant could be better for SEO and initial performance though. Static Site Generation (SSG) is supported. Also, it is more simple.

Comment: App router is better for SPAs? How, why? I'd say just use Vite if you want to create an SPA.